# Is it possible to change Amazon S3 response header `Server`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

From AWS S3, I can see that Server is set to AmazonS3.

I'm wondering if it's possible to change that to other name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit to update 2019 - please see @scrrr's answer below for a more up to date answer since the introduction of Lambda @ Edge (released a year after the answer below): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51269162/6720449

---

As far as I've seen, it's not possible to change it intrinsically with S3.  See [Common Response Headers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html) for a list of headers.

Regarding `Server` header it says:

> The name of the server that created the response.
>
> Type: String
>
> Default: AmazonS3

If you try and modify an objects header in the S3 console, the only headers you can change are:

- Cache-Control
- Content-Disposition
- Content-Type
- Content-Language
- Expires
- Content-Encoding
- Website Redirect Location

Also, you can specify custom headers if they start with `x-amz-meta-`.

If you need to present a different `Server` header, you will need to wrap access to S3 in a custom reverse proxy with header configurability - e.g. [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) on an ec2 instance.

Answer (score 10):

Yes it is, please see these blogposts [1](https://nvisium.com/resources/blog/2017/08/10/lambda-edge-cloudfront-custom-headers.html), [2](http://lukaszielinski.de/blog/posts/2018/07/10/aws-how-to-change-s3-response-headers/).

https://nvisium.com/resources/blog/2017/08/10/lambda-edge-cloudfront-custom-headers.html
http://lukaszielinski.de/blog/posts/2018/07/10/aws-how-to-change-s3-response-headers/

Comment: Is it possible to remove this header altogether?

Comment: It is worth noting that CloudFront, if you are using it, will add a server header: 'Server' 'CloudFront' if you remove it completely, but if you set it to a zero-length string, CloudFront will leave it alone.

Comment: Nice links to the posts 
One comment in 2022, Probably this task is better suited for [CloudFront Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cloudfront-functions-run-your-code-at-the-edge-with-low-latency-at-any-scale/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to change the Amazon S3 response header `Server` to another name.

The response always included the header field “Server” with the value “AmazonS3” by default. [S3 Default header IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXFji.png)

Common Response Headers From S3 : [Common Response Headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html)

For Changing the Amazon S3 response header `Server`.

Prerequisite:

1. You should have Lambda@Edge Function setup in us-east-1, N. Virginia.
2. Your website should use AWS CloudFront.

Solution:

1. Open the AWS CloudFront -> Behaviors --> Edit.
2. In the Response headers policy option you need to create a policy.
3. Enter the (policy name) --> Cross-origin resource sharing (enable) --> Custom headers option (set the header).
4. You have two options you can set "Server: None" or "Server: anyThing".
5. Save all changes, now go to the AWS CloudFront --> Invalidations --> copy to new.
6. Done, wait for all deploy

I have used this way to add "Server: None", which works for me.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to Remove the header response "Server"? I tried the "removed header" but didn't work. If not, the overriding of value is the best option.